# how to run conky on startup?i am using ubuntu lucid lynx i386

Tags: ubuntu, boot, conky

i haved configured my conky, and i want to run it on startup, i did found some tuts on internet, i haved put my conky in the startup, but in the screen, it just show just a second and gone..so how will i resolve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple...
Create .startconky at ~/

Insert the code code shown below

```
#! /bin/sh -e
sleep 15
conky
exit 0
```

Then create a Startup Application. Under System->Preferences

And at command line field.

```
/bin/sh /home/username/.startconky
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first we'd need to get to the bottom of the problem. Does running `conky` from a terminal work? We can tell for sure that conky itself is not the problem. If you go into Startup Applications and change the Conky entry to `sleep 35 && conky` does it run? Yes? Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Adding conky to my startup apps also didn't work very well for me.  Instead, I added a shell script which sleeps for about 30 seconds, and then launches conky against my customized configuration scripts.  I added that script to my startup applications.

```
#/bin/bash
sleep 30
conky -q -c ~/conkys/conkyrc_wireless.sh &
conky -q -c ~/conkys/conkyrc_weather.sh &
...
```